# Custom design for Category with exception

Tags: parent-child-theme

I have 4 themes (`desktop`, `desktop_child`, `mobile`, `mobile_child`).

I currently set `desktop` for default (desktop) theme (System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> Themes -> Default) and an exception: `mobile` for default (mobile) theme.

I set `desktop_child` as custom design for a specific category (eg: Clothing). Things work fine.

Now, I expect that when I visit Clothing category on smartphone, `mobile_child` will be applied.

How to do that?

Thank you.